# Gitlab CI: run job if any of specific jobs failed

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I use such Gitlab CI Pipeline:

```
Build  -> Deploy -> Test ---> Rollback if Build fails
                         |--> Rollback if Deploy or Test fails
```

I realized `Rollback if Build fails` in this way and it works perfectly: runs only if Build fails. Skips if Deploy or Tests fail.

```
rollback-on-build:
  when: on_failure
  needs: [ "Build" ]
```

And tried `Rollback if Deploy or Test fails`:

```
rollback-on-finish:
  when: on_failure
  needs: [ "Deploy", "Test" ]
```

And it works only if Tests fails! It skipped if Deploy fails!

**How to create job running only if fails one job from array?**

Comment: I have the same question 

Comment: There is an issue about this on Gitlab (still opened). But there is a workaround in [the thread](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/19400#note_373523646) based on artifact existence or not that seems to be interesting.

Comment: @Glandalf313 thank you! It looks like a possible solution! Maybe it is not perfect - because all jobs actually will be marked as run, not skipped, but it is really first working solution.

My current approach - to create 2 different jobs - for Deploy fail and for Test fail - using `needs` option. Also it is possible to use Dynamic child pipelines, but It looks like a bit overkill for me right now

Answer (score 1):

I did it by exporting "error" or "success" file and then I can use it to decide what should I do.
for example you can use `after_script`:

```yaml
build:
 stage: build
 script:    
   - COMMAND 2>&1 || { echo "Some errors appears, will continue" ; touch $CI_PROJECT_DIR/error ; }
 after_script:
   - if [ -e error ]; then
       echo "Seems all was done But some issues appears" ;
       <DO SOMETHING>
     fi ;
```

Also you can pass this file as `artifact` to other jobs and use `trigger.include` to dynamically create jobs if needed, e.g. as [described in gitlab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#triggerinclude).